# How to get all records from one table and irrespective of where clause

Tags: mysql

Below is my Query, when I am putting where clause, my recordset get reduced. I can understand why it reducing, 
But I am looking for all records from teacher_profiles table (31 records) and then corresponding details if there is any else blank.

Can any one suggest ? Using mySQL

```
SELECT
CONCAT(a.teacherFirstName , ' ', COALESCE(a.teacherMiddleName, ''), ' ',  a.teacherLastName ) as teacherName ,
 COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT c.subjectLongName SEPARATOR ', ') , '') AS subjects ,
 COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT f.classStd SEPARATOR ', ') , '') AS classes ,
FROM
teacher_profiles a  **<--- this table has 31 records. I need all these 31** Record in recordset
LEFT JOIN subjectteacherallocation b ON a.teacherId = b.teacherId 
LEFT JOIN subject_master c ON b.subjectId = c.subjectId
LEFT JOIN timetabledistribution d ON a.teacherId = d.teacherId
LEFT JOIN TimeTableClassSection e ON d.TimeTableClassSectionId = d.TimeTableClassSectionId
LEFT JOIN class_master f ON f.classId = e.classId
WHERE b.academicYear='2015'     <--- condition reducing record
GROUP BY a.teacherId
```

Comment: Move the condition to the `on` clause for table `b`.

Comment: @Gordon thank .. worked